# IF нажат Enter и Input.Value = 1, то <действие>

Tags: php, html

Нужно при нажатии на клавишу Enter и если в текстовом поле "message" находится 1, то выполнить действие (Имитация клика по кнопке).

```
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == 13 && "message".value=="1"){
    MsgButton.click();
    document.getElementById("message").value=""
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: `"message".value` всегда будет undefined. Возможно вы имели ввиду `document.getElementById("message").value` ?

Comment: Если вы про id, то он установлен. Связь есть.

Comment: Я не про айди. Вы написали `"message".value`. Он никогда не будет == 1, а всегда будет undefined, потому что вы пытаетесь взять значение value у строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"message".value=="1"
```

В Вашем коде опечатка. Скорее всего вы имели ввиду:

```
document.getElementById("message").value == '1'
```

`"message".value` всегда будет `undefined` (соответсвенно ваше условие никогда не выполнится), потому что у строк нет такого ключа как "value".

Comment: Да. всё верно. Огромное спасибо)